# Magento2, get custom options value in minicart observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer, custom-options, mini-cart

Using below observer the price need to be calculated based on the start and end date in custom options.

```
<?php
/**
 *  CustomPrice Observer
 *
 * @category    CustomPricing
 * @package     CustomPricing_RentPricing
 *
 */
namespace CustomPricing\RentPricing\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class CustomPrice implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        $item=$observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
        $product=$observer->getEvent()->getData('product');
        $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );
        if ($product->getData('rent_price')) {

                    $base_price= $product->getData('rent_price');

                    $number_of_days=??? how get the value of two custom options (type date)???

                    $price=$base_price * $number_of_days


            } else {
        $price = $product->getPrice();
            }
        $item->setCustomPrice($price);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
    }
}
```

Update: using below did not work

```
$product_id = $product->getId();
                    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                    $customProduct = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
                    foreach ( $customProduct ->getOptions() as $o) {
                  ??

                   }
```

Update2: Using ObjectManager is problematic here and results to `"We can't add this item to your shopping cart right now."`

Comment: Have you try using $_POST method?

Answer (score 1):

Once item (product) is quoted it will save the selected option Data(not all custom option data).
so to get the custom option you need to load the product object by `product_id` which you can get from quote object.

**Update:**
after getting the product id load the product as below.

```
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory‌​')->create()->load($‌​product_id); 
foreach ($product->getOptions() as $options) {
                $optionData = $options->getValues();
                foreach ($optionData as $data) {
                    $optionPrice[] = $data->getPrice();
                    $optionDuration[] = $data->getTitle();
                }
            }
```

Comment: May you check the post update

Comment: did you try to debug if you are really getting product_id??, check my updated answer.

Comment: The product_id is correct. Then adding your foreach results "We can't add this item to your shopping cart right now."

Comment: @Zinat since you have asked for custom option of that product, so u must be getting the custom option from the code I have suggested.. We know your logic of adding the item into the cart so can't do mare...

Answer (score 1):

Custom attribute value can be fetched in observer if it added into event form using

`$_POST['atttribute_code']`